# Gas estimation errored with the following message - 10000 NFT's

Tags: nft

I am trying to mint 10000 NFT's and created my smart contract. I get the following error when I am trying to deploy the contract. I'm not sure what im doing wrong. The error I receive is Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
gas required exceeds allowance (30000000).

Here is my code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
/**
    These contracts have been used to create tutorials, 
    please review them on your own before using any of
    the following code for production.
*/

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFT_Emojicardz is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string public baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 0.75 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 10000;
  bool public paused = false;
  mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;

  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    mint(msg.sender,10000);
  }

  // internal
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
  }

  // public
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
          require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
        }
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
  }

  function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory)
  {
    uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
    uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
    for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
      tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
    }
    return tokenIds;
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    virtual
    override
    returns (string memory)
  {
    require(
      _exists(tokenId),
      "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
    );

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension))
        : "";
  }

  //only owner
  function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner() {
    cost = _newCost;
  }

  function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner() {
    maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
  }

  function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
    baseURI = _newBaseURI;
  }

  function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension) public onlyOwner {
    baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
  }

  function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
  }
 
 function whitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = true;
  }
 
  function removeWhitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = false;
  }

  function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(success);
  }
}
```

Comment: U can’t mint that much!, the contract and transaction size is limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 30 millions gas unit.

This is the limit per block.

Maybe this could work if your the only transaction in a block.

Otherwise you will bust the gas limit.

> A final important note is that blocks themselves are bounded in size.
> Each block has a target size of 15 million gas but the size of blocks
> will increase or decrease in accordance with network demands, up until
> the block limit of 30 million gas (2x target block size). The total
> amount of gas expended by all transactions in the block must be less
> than the block gas limit. This is important because it ensures that
> blocks can’t be arbitrarily large. If blocks could be arbitrarily
> large, then less performant full nodes would gradually stop being able
> to keep up with the network due to space and speed requirements.

Source
[https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/blocks/#:~:text=Each%20block%20has%20a%20target,than%20the%20block%20gas%20limit](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/blocks/#:%7E:text=Each%20block%20has%20a%20target,than%20the%20block%20gas%20limit).

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback. I appreciate it and the knowledge I gained

Comment: You should mark it as the solution with the checkmark